# Flask-Script: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask._compat'"

Tags: python, flask, flask-script

When using Flask-Script I get an error when importing `Manager`.

I have installed Flask and Flask-Script. How do I fix this?

**manage.py**

```
from flask_script import Manager

from main import app

manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def hello():

    print ("hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

**Error**

```
(venv) raul@raul-PC:~/Proyectos Python/flask_script$ python3 manage.py hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_script import Manager
  File "/home/raul/Proyectos Python/flask_script/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from flask._compat import text_type
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask._compat'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Did you update Flask to version 2.0.0 and up?
Downgrade Flask to version **1.1.2** and it'll work.

Instead of using Flask-Script, you can simply use the following commands:

- `flask db init` to initialize the database
- `flask db migrate` to migrate new changes
- `flask db upgrade` to upgrade and so on

Comment: I just tried reinstalling Flask 2.0 with as suggest and still got the same error. You're original suggesting of using 1.1.2 seems to be the only solution there.

Comment: For those newer to Flask and some of the db operations,  in order to use the `flask db...` commands, you need to add AND init the `Migrate` object in your main Flask app file (i.e. `app.py`):

`from flask_migrate import Migrate`
...
`migrate = Migrate(app, db)`

This lets you use Flask 2.0 (which has some cool new features) without downgrading.

Comment: Does this mean that we can't use Flask-Migrate on Flask v2+ ?

Comment: @RyanAquino no, `Flask-Migrate` is available and working well! Just the `Flask-Script` is no longer used, being replaced by the better Flask CLI
at all others take a look at the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69593538/3712863 and the `Migrate Flask-Script to Flask 2.0 CLI` article

Comment: Here is my environment info of python project.
`Python 3.10.8
Flask 3.0.0  
Werkzeug 3.0.1`

And here is entire codebase.
[https://github.com/SWS-5007/TellMeWhenToGo_Python](https://github.com/SWS-5007/TellMeWhenToGo_Python)

And here is my error msg.
`
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_script\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from flask._compat import text_type
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask._compat'
`

What is wrong in my `manage.py` file code?
And how to fix this error?

Answer (score 20):

First, I installed modules manually on `PyCharm\settings\projet: myapp\python interpreter` by selecting my interpreter and installing libs missed like `Flask` itself, `flask-migrate` and `flask-script`.

For this specific error:

```
    from flask._compat import text_type
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask._compat'
```

It happened because Python searched for a `Flask._compat` directory but it isn't there, so I updated `flask_script/__init__.py` and changed the code:

On the original flask-script file:

```
from ._compat import text_type`
```

To:

```
from flask_script._compat import text_type
```

Then it works !!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it solves the problem and someone should contact `flask_script` developers to fix the issue, because error persist in the latest `Flask-Script==2.0.6` and  `Flask==2.0.1`

Comment: Flask-Script is not compatible with Flask 2.0.1 as of now. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hm, I did not checked compatibility issue but `from flask_script._compat import text_type` fix this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask._compat'`.

Comment: This is a hack solution. What's the proper solution for flask-script to work out of box with the latest python ecosystem?

Comment: @KokHowTeh By not using it at all, and switching to the newer Flask tooling and other packages. Flask-Script is dead.

Answer (score 10):

Downgrading to `flask-script==2.0.5` worked for me, even while using `Flask==2.0.2`.

Answer (score 6):

I removed

```
from flask_script import Manager
```

and

```
manager = Manager(app)
```

from my main app.

And removed Flask-Script from the requirements.txt file.

Found on github:

> flask_script is not flask itself, but a (dead - repo archived) flask extension written by someone else.

Now my program runs with Flask 2.0.1

Answer (score 4):

I installed Flask 1.1.4

```
pip install "Flask==1.1.4"
```

And also werkzeug

```
pip install "werkzeug==1.0.1"
```

Answer (score 4):

Flask-Script is unlikely to create a compatible version for Flask 2.x or any other version after [judging from their release history and last release](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Script/#history). Miguel Grinberg [explained this in his post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/migrating-from-flask-script-to-the-new-flask-cli) and the fact that the introduction of Flask CLI in Flask 0.11 may have caused the death of Flask-Script (he's not wrong the dates do corroborate).

And you do not need to downgrade from the latest version of any tech you use to build your applications. Why should you? Newer versions come with new features, better security, improved efficiency and so on. And why stick to using a library that died four years ago?

What you ought to do instead (the no-shortcut method) is to shift to Flask CLI, use the Miguel Grinberg post I linked above and continue enjoying the new features of Flask 2.0.x. [George Studenko's Medium article](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/migrating-flask-script-to-flask-2-0-cli-4a5eee269139) on the same might help you as well. It's a longer, trickier solution but ultimately more rewarding.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to downgrading Flask or Flask-Script, I used

```
from flask_login._compat import text_type
```

from the `flask_login` package, which I had in my project's dependencies, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I try Flask-Script-

1. my requirement.txt is

   ```
    click==7.1.2
    colorama==0.4.4
    Flask==1.1.4
    Flask-Script==2.0.6
    itsdangerous==1.1.0
    Jinja2==2.11.3
    MarkupSafe==2.0.1
    Werkzeug==1.0.1
   ```
2. app.py

   ```
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
   ```
3. manage.py

   ```
    from flask_script import Manager
    from app import app

    manager = Manager(app)

    @manager.command
    def hello():
        print('test')

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        manager.run()
   ```
4. run command - python manage.py hello
5. My output showing as a result "test"

Comment: For readers of this answer, the main point of this answer is to use `Flask==1.1.4` and `Flask-Script==2.0.6`, which is already mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

**Downgrading** `Flask` worked for me

Updated requirements.txt with
`Flask==1.1.4`

Answer (score -1):

You can try to downgrade you Flask version.

If you use pip, then it should be:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall flask
python3 -m pip install flask==1.1.4
```

Answer (score -1):

**Quick and Permanent Fix**:

As the error leads to line 15 of the `libs/Flask_Script/__init__.py` file, follow the steps below:

1. Replace line 15

   ```
   from ._compat import text_type on original flask-script file
   ```

   with:

   ```
   from flask_script._compat import text_type
   ```

Then,

2. Downgrade flask:

   ```
   pip install flask==1.1.4
   ```
3. Install compatible Markupsafe:

   ```
   pip install markupsafe==2.1.0
   ```

It is also good to ensure that these dependencies are installed:

```
pip install flask_script
pip install flask_bootstrap
```

Your project should work perfectly fine from this point.

Comment: This is far from "permanent", because it requires modifying the Python package file (that's not portable when deploying/running your app in other environments) and you'll get stuck at Flask <= 1.x.