# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask._compat'

Tags: python, flask

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 256, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/test_archived/test_api.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flask_api import FlaskAPI
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_api/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_api.app import FlaskAPI
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_api/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask._compat import reraise, string_types, text_type
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask._compat'
```

I tried with python version 3.6 & 3.7. Also tried flask 1.1.1, 1.1.4 & 2.0.0. But Error isn't fixing.

```
import os
import logging

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from flask import request
from flask_api import FlaskAPI
```

Error throwing FlaskAPI import
How I fixed this error?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67538056/flask-script-from-flask-compat-import-text-type-modulenotfounderror-no-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, and, finally, I defined in the `requirements.txt` the versions for both `flask` and `werkzeug`:

```
Flask==1.1.2
werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

from flask._compat import text_type ====>from flask_script._compat import text_type

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for contributing. To improve your post, the following help pages may be useful: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?])(https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also, please double check your post. I wonder if what you wrote is really what you intended to write...