# Flask script not working due to ModuleNotFoundError for flask._compat?

Tags: python, flask, server, backend, web-development-server

I tried to make messenger and got this error:

> C:\Users\VM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:\Users\VM\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\messenger\testmin.py 
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\VM\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\messenger\testmin.py", line 3, in 
> from flask_script import Manager
> File "C:\Users\VM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_script_*init*_.py", line 15, in 
> from flask._compat import text_type
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask._compat'

But I have installed flask script. Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
manager = Manager(app)


@app.route("/", methods=['get', 'post'])
def main_page():
    return render_template('main_page.html')


@app.route('/registration')
def reg():
    return render_template('registration.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=3000)
```

I tried to make the messenger and expected to get the ip and the port, but there is no, just the error above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask-Script: from flask.\_compat import text\_type ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask.\_compat'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67538056/flask-script-from-flask-compat-import-text-type-modulenotfounderror-no-module)